# How to display a label in all tabs control

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using tab control, and there is one label that showing customer's name that I want to display in all three 3 tabs. However, if I put it on tab 1, then it won't show on tab 2 and 3, even thought that the name of the label is unique. Is there a way to do that ? or do I have to create 3 different labels ? thanks a lot.

Comment: Each tab has its own contents in a TabPage. Why don't you stick the label above the tab control if it should be always visible?

Comment: Is it an option to have the label above the tabs? Otherwise you really do need to add it to all pages

Comment: @CodeCaster: I tried to move the lalel above the tab control, but it won't let me. I don't know if I did not do it correctly. Btw, I set the windows run at maximum size when it first starts, I don't know if it would prevent me to resize the tab control or not

Comment: @Sayse: it's a label that display username, so I think it should be display in all tabs.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16568164/2330053).  Just change `panel1` to `label1`, or whatever your label name is.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you.  When changing tabs.  Add the label to the TabPage's Controls collection.  When adding the label to the new TabPage it gets removed from the previous TabPage so you have to re-add it every time you change tabs.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Label label = new Label() { Text = "Hello World" };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(label);
    }

    private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
    {
        e.TabPage.Controls.Add(label);
        e.TabPage.Controls.SetChildIndex(label, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Position `label1` in your desired location in the TabPage at design-time, then switch it to the Form in the Load() event using code like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point pt = label1.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
    label1.Parent = this;
    label1.Location = this.PointToClient(pt);
    label1.BringToFront();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put on form 2 panels. 
1st panel should have Docking = Top and with height equal to height of your label. Put your label there (on 1st panel). 
2nd panel should have Docking = Fill, put your tab control on 2nd panel.